# python: removing all punctuations using string.punctuation EXCEPT a few others

Tags: python, string, punctuation

I'm trying to remove punctuations in a string called `fs` using string.punctuation with the code:

```
fs = fs.translate({ord(i): None for i in string.punctuation})
```

In the text though, there are several underlines (`_`)

How do I implement my code such that it ignores underlines and removes all others?

Is it like:

```
fs = fs.translate({ord(i): None for i in string.punctuation if '_' not in string.punctuation})
```

Comment: You must check the variable over which you iterate (which holds the single characters one by one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.punctuation` is itself just a string, so we could just work with a modified version of the string: `{ord(i): None for i in string.punctuation.replace('_', '')}`.

The more general technique you are looking for is: the `if` will be checked separately `for` each `i` value, and suppress output (of a key-value pair for the dict) when the check is false. So the condition should not be like `... if '_' not in string.punctuation`, but instead simply `... if i != '_'`.